# Populating dynamic data in CollectionView which is inside TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

**Main View Controller**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CategoryNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
    cell.lblCategoryName.text = CategoryNames[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.ViewCategogyBackground.layer.cornerRadius=20
    cell.ViewCategogyBackground.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    
    cell.arrayForCollectionView = [["xx","yy"],["zz","vv","tt"],["hello"],["11","44"]]
    cell.reloadCollectionView()
    return cell
}
```

**Table View Cell**

```
var arrayForCollectionView : [[String]]!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)       -> Int {
           if (arrayForCollectionView != nil) {
               return arrayForCollectionView.count
           }
           return 0
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryItemCollectionViewCell
             
           

           let rowValue = arrayForCollectionView[indexPath.row]
           for i in 0..<rowValue.count {
               cell.lblItemName.text = rowValue[i] as? String
           }
           return cell
       }
```

**Output**[here is my output I want to display data like first section of 2D array under t1(Category 1) and second section under t2(category 2).  both categories and items in collection view are dynamic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSuaD.png)

Comment: It's not a good idea to put CollectionView inside TableView you can implement this with CollectionView only using sections and layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CollectionView inside TableView and create outlet of collectionView inside tableViewCell like this:

```
class TimingSlotsTVCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSlotsCV: UICollectionView!
}
```

Now in your cellForRow of tableView do this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimingSlotsTVCell") as! TimingSlotsTVCell
cell.timeSlotsCV.reloadData()
return cell
```

Now collectionView cell will be called from inside tableView